# Delete images from a folder created on a Google Cloud run API

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a flask api that is running on google cloud run. For the sake of the question let it be called `https://objdetect-bbzurq6giq-as.a.run.app/objdetect`.

Using this API, a person uploads an image, the api highlights objects in the image and then stores the new image in a folder called `static`. The location of that folder is `https://objdetect-bbzurq6giq-as.a.run.app/static/`.

Now, that I am testing the API on tons of images, the capacity of the server is running out. I want to delete all the images from the static folder.

I tried the below python script but it didn't work for me, maybe thats not the right solution:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "my-project-1234"

bucket_name = 'https://objdetect-bbzurq6giq-as.a.run.app/objdetect'
directory_name = 'https://objdetect-bbzurq6giq-as.a.run.app/static/'
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# list all objects in the directory
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=directory_name)
for blob in blobs:
    blob.delete()
```

Is there a way to achieve this using a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run is not Cloud Storage. Use the Linux file system APIs to delete files stored in Cloud Run.

Use the function [os.unlink()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink)

```
path = '/static'
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.is_file():
            unlink(os.path.join(path, entry.name))
```

Comment: Or wait for the instance shut down, you will lost all you in-memory storage! (Data stored in static aren't persistent, Cloud Run is a stateless service)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud run and Cloud storage are 2 different services.

Cloud run runs within a container, we can say within a stateless machine/VM. if the images are created within the container it will get deleted once the container shuts down.

Cloud storage is like a file storage and the files within GCS will persist till explicitly deleted or deleted by a lifecycle.

So files created within cloud run are not stored within a storage rather in the in the server run in the container. If you want to delete the files inside cloud run then you would need to delete those using the code(Python in your case).